# Magento SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 145 Table './xxxxxx/log_url_info' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Tags: sql, magento

In the Magento Admin panel, try to delete a saved customer, after clicking edit, following error shows.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 145 Table './xxxxxx/log_url_info' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

Have no idea what's going on?
Please help, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes s**t happens.
You can (probably) fix this by running

```
REPAIR TABLE log_url_info;
```

on your mysql console (or phpmyadmin).

see more about repair table here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html